# Need help on active record updating via rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I had the follow code in a rake file that I will be run weekly.

```
now = Date.today
  Order.where(("status NOT IN ('Completed','Canceled','Shipped') AND DATE(updated_at) <= ?"),(now-30)).update_all("status = '*'",'Pending Requestor')
```

The problem is it is throwing wrong number of arguments error.

looking at http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class

I tried

```
now = Date.today
  Order.update_all("status = 'Pending Requester'",("status NOT IN ('Completed','Canceled','Shipped') AND DATE(updated_at) <= ?"),(now-30))
```

but that gives me a 3 for one error.

So what I need to do is I need to find all of the orders where the status is not in that list and the last time they were updated was beyond 30 days ago and automatically put them into a Pending Requester status.

Can someone help me with what I am getting wrong on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, what is assigned to the variable `now`? I'm going to assume it is `Time.now`.

Also, all of the extra parenthesis you added aren't necessary. I've simplified your query below and wrote it out so that it is easy to understand.

Change your code to:

```
Order.where(
  "status NOT IN (?) AND updated_at <= ?",       # Simplifyied the query
  %w(Completed Canceled Shipped),                # Can also be written as ['Completed', 'Canceled', 'Shipped']
  30.days.ago                                    # Self-explanatory
).update_all(status: 'Pending Requestor')
```

`where` only takes 1 argument UNLESS the argument contains question marks (`?`). For each question mark, it receives an additional argument to substitute the question mark with a value.

**Bonus:** When working with statuses in Rails, I suggest learning the [Enumerable convention](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html). It's amazing!